# How to display entire table tr in different color based on data

Tags: jquery

I am displaying Stock Symbols in a table using Jquery tableSorter .

My requirement is that if **close price is greater than yesterdays close**

I want to display the entire tr row in **green color**

Or  else

Display the entire tr row in **red color**

Similar to as shown in this fiddle (for green color display purpose)

http://jsfiddle.net/cmhmb34j/2/

This is my code

```
var resp = [{
  "prevclose_val": "1214.95",
  "low_val": "1216.05",
  "high_value": "1253.50",
  "open_value": "1220.10",
  "symbol_name": "ACC",
  "curr_day": "2016-01-29",
  "close_val": "1240.05"
}, {
  "prevclose_val": "193.20",
  "low_val": "193.00",
  "high_value": "196.50",
  "open_value": "193.95",
  "symbol_name": "AMBUJACEM",
  "curr_day": "2016-01-29",
  "close_val": "195.35"
}];
(function($) {
  var dialog = $("#popup-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
      // Will fire when this popup is opened
      // jQuery UI Dialog widget
      $('#table0').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}', // Add icon for various themes
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders'],
        widgetOptions: {
          // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
          stickyHeaders_attachTo: '#popup',
          stickyHeaders_offset: 0,
          stickyHeaders_addCaption: true
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $('.combobox').on('click', '.txt-btn', function() {
    $txtboxBtn = $(this);
    $comboboxOptions = $txtboxBtn.parent().next();
    $comboboxOptions.slideToggle();
  });
  $('.combobox-options').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
      var class_toadd = '';
      var prevclose_val = resp[i].prevclose_val;
      var low_val = resp[i].low_val;
      var high_value = resp[i].high_value;
      var open_value = resp[i].open_value;
      var symbol_name = resp[i].symbol_name;
      var curr_day = resp[i].curr_day;
      var close_val = resp[i].close_val;
      if (parseFloat(close_val > prevclose_val)) {
        class_toadd = "greenclass";
      } else if (parseFloat(close_val < prevclose_val)) {
        class_toadd = "redclass";
      }
      html += "<tr> <td>" + symbol_name + "</td><td>" + open_value + '</td> <td class="">' + high_value + '</td> <td class="">' + low_val + '</td> <td class="' + class_toadd + '">' + close_val + '</td>   <td class="">' + prevclose_val + '</td>    <td  class="">' + curr_day + "</td></tr>"
    }
    var tabid = "table0";
    $("#" + tabid + " tbody").html(html);
    $("#table0").trigger("update");
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

And this is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KxXuM/36/)

Could you please let me know how to display it in red or green color based on dynamic data ??

Comment: `if (parseFloat(close_val > prevclose_val))` should be `if (parseFloat(close_val) > parseFloat(prevclose_val))...` (the same for the `else if` branch)

Comment: remove `parseFloat` at your if clause

Comment: As usual, you (all your team) didn't put any effort to resolve your issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem in your condition so the class will be not assigned to the `class_toadd` variable, you should replace :

```
if (parseFloat(close_val > prevclose_val)) {
    class_toadd = "greenclass";
} else if (parseFloat(close_val < prevclose_val)) {
    class_toadd = "redclass";
}
```

By :

```
if (parseFloat(close_val) > parseFloat(prevclose_val)) {
    class_toadd = "greenclass";
} else if (parseFloat(close_val) < parseFloat(prevclose_val)) {
    class_toadd = "redclass";
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var resp = [{
  "prevclose_val": "1214.95",
  "low_val": "1216.05",
  "high_value": "1253.50",
  "open_value": "1220.10",
  "symbol_name": "ACC",
  "curr_day": "2016-01-29",
  "close_val": "1240.05"
}, {
  "prevclose_val": "193.20",
  "low_val": "193.00",
  "high_value": "196.50",
  "open_value": "193.95",
  "symbol_name": "AMBUJACEM",
  "curr_day": "2016-01-29",
  "close_val": "195.35"
}];
(function($) {
  var dialog = $("#popup-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
      // Will fire when this popup is opened
      // jQuery UI Dialog widget
      $('#table0').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}', // Add icon for various themes
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders'],
        widgetOptions: {
          // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
          stickyHeaders_attachTo: '#popup',
          stickyHeaders_offset: 0,
          stickyHeaders_addCaption: true
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $('.combobox').on('click', '.txt-btn', function() {
    $txtboxBtn = $(this);
    $comboboxOptions = $txtboxBtn.parent().next();
    $comboboxOptions.slideToggle();
  });
  $('.combobox-options').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
      var class_toadd = '';
      var prevclose_val = resp[i].prevclose_val;
      var low_val = resp[i].low_val;
      var high_value = resp[i].high_value;
      var open_value = resp[i].open_value;
      var symbol_name = resp[i].symbol_name;
      var curr_day = resp[i].curr_day;
      var close_val = resp[i].close_val;
      if (parseFloat(close_val) > parseFloat(prevclose_val)) {
        class_toadd = "greenclass";
      } else if (parseFloat(close_val) < parseFloat(prevclose_val)) {
        class_toadd = "redclass";
      }
      html += "<tr> <td>" + symbol_name + "</td><td>" + open_value + '</td> <td class="">' + high_value + '</td> <td class="">' + low_val + '</td> <td class="' + class_toadd + '">' + close_val + '</td>   <td class="">' + prevclose_val + '</td>    <td  class="">' + curr_day + "</td></tr>"
    }
    var tabid = "table0";
    $("#" + tabid + " tbody").html(html);
    $("#table0").trigger("update");
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#popup-dialog {
    display: none;
}


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

html, input, textarea, a {
    font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Montserrat';    
}

input[type=text].txtbox {
    color: #000000;
    height: 60px;
    width: 260px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    padding-left: 21px;
    outline: none;
}

.txt-btn {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -999999px;
}

.txt-btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 1.3em;
  width: 2em;
  height: 0.2em;
  box-shadow: 
    0 0.45em 0 0 white,
    0 0.90em 0 0 white;
}

.combobox {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 60px;
}

.combobox input[type=text].txtbox, .combobox .txt-btn {
    position: absolute;
}

.combobox .txt-btn {
    right: 0;
}

.combobox  + .combobox-options {
    width: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #1f7f5c;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.combobox  + .combobox-options li {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid  #2a8664;
    line-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.greenclass
{
 color:#080!important;
 font-weight:bold
}
.redclass
{
 color:#c00!important;
 font-weight:bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<div class="combobox">
    <input class="txtbox" type="text" placeholder="" />
    <a href="#" class="txt-btn">Select</a>
</div>
<ul class="combobox-options">
    <li>Click Here For Symbols List</li>
    
</ul>


<div id="popup-dialog">
    <table id="table0" class="tablesorter">
     <!--   <caption>Student Grades</caption>-->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Open</th>
                <th>High</th>
                <th>Low</th>
                <th>Close</th>
                <th>Prev. Close</th>
                <th class="sorter-false">Day</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Open</th>
                <th>High</th>
                <th>Low</th>
                <th>Close</th>
                <th>Prev. Close</th>
                <th>Day</th>
                <th class="sorter-false">Day</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

If you want to display the entire tr row in color depending to the variable `class_toadd` you can assign thi class to the `tr` in :

```
html += "<tr class="+class_toadd+"> <td>" + symbol_name + "</td><td>" ...
```

```js
var resp = [{
  "prevclose_val": "1214.95",
  "low_val": "1216.05",
  "high_value": "1253.50",
  "open_value": "1220.10",
  "symbol_name": "ACC",
  "curr_day": "2016-01-29",
  "close_val": "1240.05"
}, {
  "prevclose_val": "193.20",
  "low_val": "193.00",
  "high_value": "196.50",
  "open_value": "193.95",
  "symbol_name": "AMBUJACEM",
  "curr_day": "2016-01-29",
  "close_val": "195.35"
}];
(function($) {
  var dialog = $("#popup-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
      // Will fire when this popup is opened
      // jQuery UI Dialog widget
      $('#table0').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}', // Add icon for various themes
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders'],
        widgetOptions: {
          // jQuery selector or object to attach sticky header to
          stickyHeaders_attachTo: '#popup',
          stickyHeaders_offset: 0,
          stickyHeaders_addCaption: true
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $('.combobox').on('click', '.txt-btn', function() {
    $txtboxBtn = $(this);
    $comboboxOptions = $txtboxBtn.parent().next();
    $comboboxOptions.slideToggle();
  });
  $('.combobox-options').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
      var class_toadd = '';
      var prevclose_val = resp[i].prevclose_val;
      var low_val = resp[i].low_val;
      var high_value = resp[i].high_value;
      var open_value = resp[i].open_value;
      var symbol_name = resp[i].symbol_name;
      var curr_day = resp[i].curr_day;
      var close_val = resp[i].close_val;
      if (parseFloat(close_val) > parseFloat(prevclose_val)) {
        class_toadd = "greenclass";
      } else if (parseFloat(close_val) < parseFloat(prevclose_val)) {
        class_toadd = "redclass";
      }
      html += "<tr class="+class_toadd+"> <td>" + symbol_name + "</td><td>" + open_value + '</td> <td class="">' + high_value + '</td> <td class="">' + low_val + '</td> <td class="' + class_toadd + '">' + close_val + '</td>   <td class="">' + prevclose_val + '</td>    <td  class="">' + curr_day + "</td></tr>"
    }
    var tabid = "table0";
    $("#" + tabid + " tbody").html(html);
    $("#table0").trigger("update");
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#popup-dialog {
    display: none;
}


@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

html, input, textarea, a {
    font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Montserrat';    
}

input[type=text].txtbox {
    color: #000000;
    height: 60px;
    width: 260px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    padding-left: 21px;
    outline: none;
}

.txt-btn {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -999999px;
}

.txt-btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 1.3em;
  width: 2em;
  height: 0.2em;
  box-shadow: 
    0 0.45em 0 0 white,
    0 0.90em 0 0 white;
}

.combobox {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 60px;
}

.combobox input[type=text].txtbox, .combobox .txt-btn {
    position: absolute;
}

.combobox .txt-btn {
    right: 0;
}

.combobox  + .combobox-options {
    width: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #1f7f5c;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.combobox  + .combobox-options li {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid  #2a8664;
    line-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.greenclass
{
 color:#080!important;
 font-weight:bold
}
.redclass
{
 color:#c00!important;
 font-weight:bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<div class="combobox">
    <input class="txtbox" type="text" placeholder="" />
    <a href="#" class="txt-btn">Select</a>
</div>
<ul class="combobox-options">
    <li>Click Here For Symbols List</li>
    
</ul>


<div id="popup-dialog">
    <table id="table0" class="tablesorter">
     <!--   <caption>Student Grades</caption>-->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Open</th>
                <th>High</th>
                <th>Low</th>
                <th>Close</th>
                <th>Prev. Close</th>
                <th class="sorter-false">Day</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Open</th>
                <th>High</th>
                <th>Low</th>
                <th>Close</th>
                <th>Prev. Close</th>
                <th>Day</th>
                <th class="sorter-false">Day</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

If you want to display the entire tr row background you should create another classes for this and assign it to another variable in your condition and pass the variable to the `tr` class , e.g :

```
.bg-red-class
{
     background-color:#c00!important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jQuery.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for this purpose:

```
$("yourTable tr").filter(function(index) {
    return someTest($(this));
}).css("background-color", "yourColor");
```

Check [this page](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for more info.